# Add second store to magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore, htaccess

I'm trying to add a second store to my existing Magento installation (1.8.1.0).

The existing instance sits on `https://subdomain1.url.com`, 
Within Magento, website code is base, store view code is default

The 2nd instance is to sit on `http://subdomain2.url.com`,
Within Magento, Website code is 2ndstore, store view code is 2ndstore_sv

I have amended the configuration within Magento so that the new subdomain is configured for the store (System -> Configuration -> Web -> Base URL)

I have set up subdomain2 within cPanel and the root is pointing to subdomain1

Within the htaccess file I have the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)subdomain2.url.com
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:2ndstore_sv]
```

Yet when I type `http://subdomain2.url.com` into the browser I end up at 
`https://subdomain1.url.com`

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should point the **DNS** of the second store to  `https://subdomain2.url.com`   and add the **alias** in your Vhost.
2. Add this in your **.htaccess**

   ```
   SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE website
   SetEnvIf Host subdomain1\.url\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1
   SetEnvIf Host subdomain2\.url\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2
   ```
3. Add the code bellow in your **index.php** above this: `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`

   ```
   switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
       case 'subdomain1.url.com':
       case 'www.subdomain1.url.com':
           $mageRunCode = 'domain1';
           $mageRunType = 'website';
       break;
       case 'subdomain2.url.com':
       case 'www.subdomain2.url.com':
           $mageRunCode = 'domain2';
           $mageRunType = 'website';
       break;
   }
   ```

Comment: Excellent, all working now, thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome :) please accept the answer.